# find two words in a string and copy everything in between them

Tags: python

I would like to be able to get the string in between to words of my choice. For example :

```
x = "Hello My Name is John Doe"
```

I would like the program to return a string holding the values in between Hello and Doe - `"My Name is John "`

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you attempted? What is your specific issue? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Read about `str.find()` and think how you can use it together with slicing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x = re.search("Hello (.*)Doe",
      "Hello My Name is John Doe")
if x:
    print x.groups()[0]
```